# Save Jquery var sum in DB MySQL

Tags: php, jquery, save, var

I'm using jquery to sum values of input checkbox and i need to save the sum into DB MySQL but how can i put the value in a php var? I don't know how can i do this.

Can someone help me out? I'm newbie in jquery :/

Here's the code i'm using:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {     
        function recalculate() {
            var sum = 0;

            $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function() {
                var val = $(this).attr("preco").replace(',', '.'); 
                sum += parseFloat(val);
            });

            $("#output").html(sum);
        }

        $("input[type=checkbox]").change(function() {
            recalculate();
        });
});
</script>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
$transporte = $_POST['metodoenvio'];

 (... save into DB)
}
?>

<span id="output"></span> // the sum in html shows up here

<form class="cmxform" id="pedidoForm" method="post" action="">
<input type="checkbox" name="metodoenvio" class="metodoenvio" preco="20" />
<input type="checkbox" name="metodoenvio" class="metodoenvio" preco="10" />
(...)
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: So what's the *problem?*

Comment: If you're just trying to post the `SUM` back to the server, can't you just use an `.ajax` or `.post` method?

Answer (score 1):

Take a hidden type variable with some id in form tag and put value in `hidden variable` by  `jquery` like:

```
$("#hidden_var").val(sum);
```

Then at the end submit the form

Answer (score 0):

add new hidden input field to the form to hold the sum

```
    <form class="cmxform" id="pedidoForm" method="post" action="">
//add new hidden input field to have the sum
<input id="sum_input" name="sum" type="hidden"/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="metodoenvio" class="metodoenvio" preco="20" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="metodoenvio" class="metodoenvio" preco="10" />
    (...)
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="submit"/>
    </form>
```

//Then use the jquery to put the sum to input id sum

```
function recalculate() {
            var sum = 0;

            $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function() {
                var val = $(this).attr("preco").replace(',', '.'); 
                sum += parseFloat(val);
            });

            $("#output").html(sum);
           //jquery to put sum into form
            $("#sum_input").val(sum);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should split your php server side scripts out of your html/js client side pages.  create a separate php page so process the data and call it through an ajax call.

change your submit button to just be a button and attach an onclick event to call a function that will sum the checkboxes and then initiate the and ajax request.

```
<script>
function sumChecked(){
  i = 0;
  $.each($('#pedidoForm:ckecked), function({
    i++;
  });
  $.ajax({
    url:"yourPHPpage.php",
    type:"POST",
    data:{"sumVar":i},
    success: function(data){
      alert ("Process Complete");
    }
  })
}
...
</script>
...
<form class="cmxform" id="pedidoForm">
<input type="checkbox" name="metodoenvio" class="metodoenvio" preco="20" />
<input type="checkbox" name="metodoenvio" class="metodoenvio" preco="10" />
(...)
<input type="button" name="submit" id="submit" value="submit" onClick="sumChecked()"/>
</form>
```

then on your php page catch the $_POST['sumVar'] variable sent through from the form and do whatever you want to server-side with that info.